# Many to Many entity Problems

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, orm

I stumpled on another problem I can't seem to solve.
[Sample Pictures](http://www.pic-upload.de/gal-831993/isarqn/1.html)

With the help of the pictures I hope you can see what I want.
I have an interface where the user selects an printertype. After the printertype is selected, all FAQ which are linked to this printertype should be shown.

There is no model for the printertypeFAQ table, only `this.printertype = new HashSet<printertype>();` and `public virtual ICollection<printertype> printertype { get; set; }` can be found in the printertype and FAQ models.

I can't access the printertypeFAQ table which is importent for me. 
Could you help me how to access the table and save data in it?

```
faq.printertype = db.printertypeSatz.Include(i => faq.printertype).Where(i => i.ID == _Type).Single();
```

The one above doesn't work for example.

I appreciate all help.

Thank you

Comment: Your naming convention is killing me bit by bit.... make sure your `Properties` start with a *C*apital letter, and your `Fields` all lowercase with an optional underscore preceding it

Comment: Why don't you have a link table? Link tables can be a pain... you would have to do something like a left join / right join which under the scenes would use the link table.

Comment: The HashSet and ICollection are typical facets of data annotation code first method for defining a one to many, which I would expect to see in both models for a many to many... see http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Confused.com ... wtf ... you say "There is no model for the printertypeFAQ table"... there is no printertypeFAQ in your images so why on earth would there be a model for it? ... you say "I can't access the printertypeFAQ" ...  there is no printertypeFAQ table / entity!

Comment: Which ORM ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software

Comment: Visual Studio tells me that I use ADO.NET Entity Data Model. the schema is DBO. There is a PrintertypeFAQ in my images! the first image shows printertypeFAQ as a table and is my server-explorer in visual studio. Hope that clears it up a bit.

Comment: [some more pictures](http://www.pic-upload.de/gal-832039/hnaei/1.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

At the beginning I create

```
        private void PopulatePrintertypeDropDownList(object selectedPrintertype = null)
    {
        var printertypeQuery = from p in db.printertypeSatz
                               orderby p.Type
                               select p;
        ViewBag.printertypeID = new SelectList(printertypeQuery, "ID", "Type", selectedPrintertype);
    }
```

and after this I edited the ActionResult like this

```
[Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(FAQ faq, List<int> printertypes)
    {
        PopulatePrintertypeDropDownList();
        foreach (int i in printertypes)
        {
            faq.printertype.Add(db.printertypeSatz.Find(i));
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.FAQSatz.Add(faq);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(faq);
    }
```

Now everything is working just as I wanted it to.

Sorry for everybody who got an headache while reading my problem, 
also thanks to all answers.

Answer (score 1):

So this will get the printertype entity according to the Primary Key

```
var _printertype = db.printertypeSatz.Find(_ID);
```

Once you have this you can access the FAQ like so

```
foreach (var _faq in _printertype.FAQ) { Console.WriteLine(_faq.Headline); }
```

I suppose you would only want to make one DB call and so you could try the following to get the printertype with related FAQs

```
foreach (var _faq in db.printertypeSatz.Find(_ID).FAQ) { Console.WriteLine(_faq.Headline); }
```

Hope it helps ?

Comment: Yeah thanks. This one helped me to think in another direction.